# MySQL: INSERT SELECT to two databases (STORED FUNCTION)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, copy

I have to copy values of two twowith slight differences. One of the databases has to get the new corresponding id of the other. Hard to explain, so I'll do it with an example:

These tables are created:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema testing
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `testing` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `testing` ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `testing`.`table1`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testing`.`table1` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `testing`.`table2`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testing`.`table2` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_table1` INT NOT NULL,
  `value` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `id_table1_idx` (`id_table1` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `id_table1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_table1`)
    REFERENCES `testing`.`table1` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The values of table1 are:

```
--------------------
| id  |    value   |
|------------------|
|  1  | 'Abra'     |
|  2  | 'Simsala'  |
--------------------
```

The values of table2 are:

```
-------------------------------
| id  | id_table1 |  value    |
|-----------------------------|
|  1  |     1     | 'Kadabra' |
|  2  |     2     | 'Bim'     |
-------------------------------
```

I want to copy all of the values including new foreign keys using a stored function. So that the results will be:

table1:

```
--------------------
| id  |    value   |
|------------------|
|  1  | 'Abra'     |
|  2  | 'Simsala'  |
|  3  | 'Abra'     |
|  4  | 'Simsala'  |
--------------------
```

table2:

```
-------------------------------
| id  | id_table1 |  value    |
|-----------------------------|
|  1  |     1     | 'Kadabra' |
|  2  |     2     | 'Bim'     |
|  3  |     3     | 'Kadabra' |
|  4  |     4     | 'Bim'     |
-------------------------------
```

Of course my real problem is much more complicated, but much harder to describe to. So I hope someone knows an answer how to do it in a stored function.

Comment: Sometimes `FOREIGN KEYS` are more trouble than they are worth.